# How can I force 'scatter.smooth' to label the x-axis with strings rather than numbers, ordered the way I mean it?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am experimenting with `R`'s `scatter.plot` and have written the following scriptlet:

```
d <- data.frame(
  weekday = rep(c('So', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'), 5),
  value   = nchar(c(
 '##'                 , # So
 '########'           , # Mo
 '#############'      , # Tu
 '######'             , # We
 '############'       , # Th
 '###############'    , # Fr
 '###'                , # Sa
# ---
 '####'               , # So
 '####'               , # Mo
 '########'           , # Tu
 '#####'              , # We
 '###########'        , # Th
 '#########'          , # Fr
 '#####'              , # Sa
# ---
 '####'               , # So
 '######'             , # Mo
 '############'       , # Tu
 '####'               , # We
 '#############'      , # Th
 '##########'         , # Fr
 '###'                , # Sa
# ---
 '#'                  , # So
 '####'               , # Mo
 '##############'     , # Tu
 '####'               , # We
 '############'       , # Th
 '##############'     , # Fr
 '#######'            , # Sa
# ---
 '###'                , # So
 '######'             , # Mo
 '###########'        , # Tu
 '######'             , # We
 '#############'      , # Th
 '###########'        , # Fr
 '####'                 # Sa
 ))
)

scatter.smooth(d$value ~ d$weekday, col=gray(0.7), bty='n')
```

This produces the following plot:
[image]

There are two problems for me: The x-axis is labeled with numbers rather than `So`, `Mo` through `Sa` and the numbers seems to be ordered according to the alphabetical value of the weekday they represent (so 1 is `Fr` and 7 is `We`).

How can I have the plot show me the weekday labels (`So` through `Sa`) in the order of the weekdays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll want to reorder the factor levels of `weekday` (which you correctly noticed defaults to alphabetical):

```
d$weekday = factor(d$weekday, levels= c('So', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'))
```

Then you'll want to use the `levels` of the weekday data to replace the x-axis's numbers:

```
scatter.smooth(d$value ~ d$weekday, col=gray(0.7), bty='n', xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:7, labels = levels(d$weekday))
```

Adding the `xaxt="n"` says first to not use the default number scheme for the x-axis, then the `axis` function places the custom labels.

[image]